# VisualState Storyboard change GridView Orientation

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I want to change the orientation of a `GridView` using a `Storyboard`.

I've tried the following but the property `(ItemsPanel.Orientation)` does not exist:

```
<ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="defaultNavigation" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ItemsPanel.Orientation)">
   <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Horizontal"/>
</ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Is this possible without having to add a separate `GridView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I added the following `Style` to the `Page.Resources` and in the `VisualState` `StoryBoard` I changed the Style of the GridView to this style.

```
<Style TargetType="GridView" x:Key="HorizontalItemsPanelStyle">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
</Style>
```